# How to determine which nunit tests to run or ignore while building in build server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, msbuild, nunit

I want to specify a subset of my test to run while a project builds in build server an so its integrated tests run.

I've found a solution for `MSTest` tests here:
[Ignore test categories in TFS build server using DefaultTemplate.xaml](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/07/ignore-test-categories-in-tfs-build-server-using-defaulttemplate-xaml/)

but it doesn't work for Nunit.

I've found `Category` attribute for Nunit but setting this in the build template doesn't work:

```
Category=IntegrationTest
```

while I marked my tests like:

```
[Category("IntegrationTest")]
[TestFixture]
public MyTestClass ...
```

Comment: Why do you have them in the same project? I would recommend separating the integration tests to a separate assembly. Since they are different "things" they "should" be separated..!

Comment: @Jocke Yep, you're right. As a matter of fact, I've come to the same result too. I separated them now. I think your comment can be posted as answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom category (inherit Category class) then in your build script you can ignore this category

This is a example for psake + mstest but it could be easily applied to NUnit and whatever build system are you using

http://log.ld.si/post/longrunningtests-as-a-separate-psake-task

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have them in the same project? I would recommend separating the integration tests to a separate assembly. Since they are different "things" they "should" be separated!

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same problems and i came up with this Solution.
Place your UnitTests in one (or more) Projects and your IntegrationTests in another Project (or more than one).
The clue is to identify that its UnitTest or IntegrationTest by the project name.
For example we named all our UnitTest Projects "UnitTest" besides other specific description.

Then in your builddefinition you can describe the filter which dlls the buildserver should use to load unittests and only load dlls which contain of UnitTest in the filename.